# Some autocard names don't execute correctly

Tags: bug, status-declined, magic-the-gathering, mtg-autocard

`[mtg:Grafdigger's Cage]` fails to find any cards (Try it: [Grafdigger's Cage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrafdigger%27s%5d%2b%5bCage%5d)). I've double-checked it a few times. I think it's something about the `'` in the card name.

(*This is very minor*) `[mtg:Sun Titan]` takes you a search page with Sun Titan and Sundering Titan. (Try it: [Sun Titan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSun%20Titan%5d))

I'm not sure whether these are bugs on our part or limitations in the Gatherer interface we're using.

See [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/7416/1910) for how this came up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the Magic card auto link feature be improved?](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/can-the-magic-card-auto-link-feature-be-improved)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of our more recent request on the matter.

Comment: @doppelgreener As the original poster, I'm fine with that. Especially since the other question calls out exactly how to fix it. Plz close as dupe, everyone.

Comment: VTC as duplicate of the newer thread, in which this was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You'll notice similar problems on the Daily Magic website itself whenever apostrophes are involved. I believe it's something to do with either escaping or straight vs. curled apostrophes.

Edit: If it weren't for the authocard, it would be relatively easy to fix. Sun Titan returns

```
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+[sun]+[titan]
```

If it were

```
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+[sun titan]
```

there would be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

My best guesses from messing with Gatherer:

- `[mtg:Grafdigger's Cage]` seems to be an issue with Gatherer itself, but it can be worked around on our side by stripping the link text -- basically kill any text between the `'` and the next whitespace, so you submit "Grafdigger Cage" to the search script.
- Circeus has an answer about what to do with `[mtg:Sun Titan]`.

---

It looks like you can fix the apostrophe issue by just replacing `%27` with `%20` in the autocard links (and leave any floating characters just the way they are).

E.g. `http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=[Liliana%20s%20Specter]`

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with the autocard api, it doesn't look like we can fix this.

I'm forced to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) as the problem is on Wizards end, and I doubt they'll be addressing it.  Every time we contact them we don't really get anywhere.

Comment: It's their bug, but it seems like we can work around it while still respecting their terms and conditions. E.g. change `http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Grafdigger%27s%20Cage` to `http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=[Grafdigger%20Cage]`

Comment: I ran into this today and it was particularly frustrating. To further to cause of getting this fixed, I compiled a list of all cards with an apostrophe or ampersand, with their appropriate multiverse-id, in the following pastebin: http://pastebin.com/5P6WbPiY Perhaps you could put those in a handy map and, if you get a match on them, link directly to the card instead of to the search page (assuming this isn't against their terms of service).  Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: It can easily be fixed using `s/'/ /g`

Comment: Later down the road we found it wasn't so much a problem with the API, but us using the wrong part of the API. We're closing this as a dupe of [the newer question](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/can-the-magic-card-auto-link-feature-be-improved) which has the details in an answer.