# Autocard doesn't find a specific card, Sakashima the Impostor

Tags: bug, magic-the-gathering, mtg-autocard

Title. [Sakashima the Impostor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSakashima%20the%20Impostor%5d) returns no search result on the gatherer site for some reason. Autocarding [Sakashima](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSakashima%5d) or [Impostor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bImpostor%5d) alone at least takes me to the search function that includes the wanted card, but any combination of 2 or all 3 words fails to deliver any result, e.g.

[Sakashima the](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSakashima%20the%5d)

[the Impostor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bthe%20Impostor%5d)

[Sakashima Impostor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSakashima%20Impostor%5d)

Other multi-word autocards function just fine. "Sakashima the Impostor" doesn't even contain special characters or any of the other common autocard failure modes, my language is also set to English.

I noted that there is a [Sakashima the Impostor Avatar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSakashima%20the%20Impostor%20Avatar%5d) card, a Vanguard card that is not typically included in search results. Is that the problem? However, that must be a recent change of the search algorithm, because both the regular Sakashima and the Vanguard card are old entries, and in my answer of [How to clone a Legendary card legally?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29751/how-to-clone-a-legendary-card-legally) I linked Sakashima and it used to work back then.

Test for other Vanguard duplicate names:

[Akroma, Angel of Wrath](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAkroma%2c%20Angel%20of%20Wrath%5d)

[Arcbound Overseer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArcbound%20Overseer%5d)

[Arcanis, the Omnipotent](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArcanis%2c%20the%20Omnipotent%5d) (this goes straight to the avatar page instead of the regular card)

[Ashling the Pilgrim](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAshling%20the%20Pilgrim%5d)

[Birds of Paradise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBirds%20of%20Paradise%5d)

[Bosh, Iron Golem](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBosh%2c%20Iron%20Golem%5d)

[Braids, Conjurer Adept](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBraids%2c%20Conjurer%20Adept%5d)

[Chronatog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChronatog%5d)

[Dakkon Blackblade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDakkon%20Blackblade%5d)

[Dauntless Escort](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDauntless%20Escort%5d)

[Diamond Faerie](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDiamond%20Faerie%5d)

[Eight-and-a-Half-Tails](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEight-and-a-Half-Tails%5d)

[Eladamri, Lord of Leaves](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEladamri%2c%20Lord%20of%20Leaves%5d)

[Elvish Champion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElvish%20Champion%5d)

[Enigma Sphinx](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEnigma%20Sphinx%5d)

[Erhnam Djinn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bErhnam%20Djinn%5d)

[Etched Oracle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEtched%20Oracle%5d)

[Fallen Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFallen%20Angel%5d)

[Figure of Destiny](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFigure%20of%20Destiny%5d)

[Flametongue Kavu](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFlametongue%20Kavu%5d)

[Frenetic Efreet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFrenetic%20Efreet%5d)

[Goblin Warchief](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoblin%20Warchief%5d)

[Grinning Demon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrinning%20Demon%5d)

[Haakon, Stromgald Scourge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHaakon%2c%20Stromgald%20Scourge%5d)

I don't feel like typing all of them out, but you get the idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some autocard names don't execute correctly](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/794/some-autocard-names-dont-execute-correctly)

Comment: Arcanis is different because the corresponding creature card doesn't have a comma in its name.

Comment: @murgatroid99 How many different posts do we need stating that the autocard feature is broken?

Comment: The previous post was escalated to the development team a while ago. The rest is up to them.

Answer (score 2):

> I noted that there is a Sakashima the Impostor Avatar card, a Vanguard card that is not typically included in search results. Is that the problem?

Yep, that's the problem exactly.

When a card name is two or more words, *and* there is another card that contains that card's name, the search will return no results at all. This is true for "Sakashima the Impostor" because of "Sakashima the Impostor Avatar", and just about every other avatar as you've discovered.

(If it's just one word, e.g. "Island" or "Recall" or the "Chronatog" you found, we're given a search page that includes the card, but not the card's page directly. This is also undesirable.)

There's two current requests to improve our Gatherer search:

- A request to change the Gatherer link formula to another: [Can the Autocard feature be improved (again)?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1727/5573). This formula was also proposed [in 2014](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1160/5573) ([actually twice](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1156/5573)) to fix some issues in autocard v1, but another option was implemented for the current v2.
- The alternative is switching over to a third party MTG search engine: [Switch Magic autocard over to a different search engine, Scryfall](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1652/5573)

The new Gatherer formula resolves our current major problems such as this one. (There are some test cases where it doesn't work quite perfectly in either English or foreign languages.) Scryfall passes all test cases but isn't the official source.

Comment: Ok, I thought that change was already implemented. Why was it not yet?

Comment: We implemented a different change for our current autocard. There was a change, just not this one.